# Say 'Hello World!' in Openshift with Node.js

Tags: node.js, openshift

I created an app in Openshift and created a local git repo on my computer. I want to change the default welcome page here: http://nodejs-j4nos.rhcloud.com:3000 and just tell Hello world as [this](http://expressjs.com/starter/hello-world.html) tutorial say.

So I removed from local repo the index.html, and modified server.js, pasted in this code below. And commit, and push. I get a long approval, that they accepted my commit.

If I good understand I do not have to stop node and start it again, but Openshift do it for me. But as you can see no Hello World is able to see, when open link in browser (http://nodejs-j4nos.rhcloud.com:3000) why?

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();

app.get('/', function (req, res) {
  res.send('Hello World!');
});

var server = app.listen(3000, function () {

  var host = server.address().address;
  var port = server.address().port;

  console.log('Example app listening at http://%s:%s', host, port);

});
```

---

```
remote: Git Post-Receive Result: success        
remote: Activation status: success        
remote: Deployment completed with status: success        
To ssh://5556b4c4fcf9336abf0000de@nodejs-j4nos.rhcloud.com/~/git/nodejs.git/
```

and here is the tree structure, `express` is listed

[image]

Based on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22582725/deployed-node-app-to-openshift-successfully-openshift-still-shows-default-page?rq=1) SO answer I tried to modify script, but does not helped:

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();

app.set('port', process.env.OPENSHIFT_NODEJS_PORT || 8080);
app.set('ip', process.env.OPENSHIFT_NODEJS_IP || '127.0.0.1');

http.createServer(app).listen(app.get('port'), app.get('ip'), function(){
  console.log('Express server listening on port ' + app.get('port'));
});

app.get('/', function (req, res) {
  res.send('Hello World!');
});
```

Comment: did u tried opening not the :3000 port? just http://nodejs-j4nos.rhcloud.com ??? when having the app up??¿?¿ 

Express is suposed to work behind the http and the node firewall or apache firewall is who redirects the port 80 to 3000.

Comment: https://developers.openshift.com/en/node-js-getting-started.html#launch

Comment: @Alejandro Teixeira Muñoz changed 3000 to 80 but still stuck

Comment: no, don´t change your port on code to :80, just write in the url of the browser the url without :3000.

as appears in @zipzit link, your app should be in   URL:        http://myapp-shifter.rhcloud.com/  when it´s available. Not in  http://nodejs-j4nos.rhcloud.com:3000. Please, follow again the steps and try to enter again with http://nodejs-j4nos.rhcloud.com <-- after reinstalling

Comment: maybe with the answer i posted? `port > 15000  && < 35530` ?

Comment: @AlejandroTeixeiraMuñoz changed back to port 3000 and tested without `:3000` but does not work

Comment: anyway, in my server, i have different apps installed. I use apache to redirect all of them. Each node app runs in a port F.Ex 12000, but when the user reaches by the http (80) the desired domain for each app, it´s redirected to the directory and to the port . Then the user connects to 80 and server bridges (transparent to user) to node app (12000) in my case.

Comment: @AlejandroTeixeiraMuñoz `port > 15000 && < 35530` also fails

Comment: It seems like if some openshift mapping is not working. when I visit   nodejs-j4nos.rhcloud.com it appears the unavailable message. It´s the same that happens in my server when my app is stopped on the server.

Comment: Are you making it to: `console.log('Example app listening at http://%s:%s', host, port);` ??  Do we bring this over to chat?

Comment: @zipzit  I changed nothing in the tutorial, just playing with port

Comment: Chat Hello World room Click on upper menu stack exchange, then chat? Look for Hello World?

Comment: Check the chapter 2 here:
http://middlewaremagic.com/jboss/?p=2305

Comment: and check that https://blog.openshift.com/set-up-local-access-to-openshift-hosted-services-with-port-forwarding/ 

maybe with those tutorials you will find the problem.I have to go now. Will check again later for updates!!

Comment: http://nodejs-j4nos.rhcloud.com/ <-- IT´s working!!!+

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Link is working now: http://nodejs-j4nos.rhcloud.com The right script to show "Hello world!" is

```
var http = require('http');
var express = require('express');
var app = express();

app.set('port', process.env.OPENSHIFT_NODEJS_PORT || 8080);
app.set('ip', process.env.OPENSHIFT_NODEJS_IP || '127.0.0.1');

http.createServer(app).listen(app.get('port'), app.get('ip'), function(){
  console.log('Express server listening on port ' + app.get('port'));
});

app.get('/', function (req, res) {
  res.send('Hello World!');
});
```

And here is the proof:

[image]

Thanks for this: [Deployed Node app to OpenShift successfully, OpenShift still shows default page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22582725/deployed-node-app-to-openshift-successfully-openshift-still-shows-default-page?rq=1)
and this question: [Node.js Deployment in openshift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19255186/node-js-deployment-in-openshift?rq=1)

And you should now that you can write in `/app-root/repo` the `$ node server.js` command, and if something wrong with script, it will indicate right there

Answer (score 0):

Found my notes on using OpenShift with Node:
The openshift system has some integrated control tools to support its ‘gear’ system, useful to control the openshift
application and environment.

```
gear            control your application (start, stop, restart, etc)
                or deps with --cart      (gear start --cart mysql-5.1)
tail_all        tail all log files. This command displays the last entries
                in your log files as they are written.  You can hit 
                <ctrl>-c to exit this command.
export          list available environment variables
rm              remove files / directories
ls              list files / directories
ps              list running applications
kill            kill running applications
mysql           interactive MySQL shell
mongo           interactive MongoDB shell
psql            interactive PostgreSQL shell
quota           list disk usage
```

The gear system has additional commands.  OpenShift Gear Control, An assortment of gear utilities:

COMMANDS:

```
build                Run the build steps
deploy               Run the deploy steps
help                 Display global or [command] help documentation.
postreceive          Run the git postreceive steps
prereceive           Run the git prereceive steps
reload               Reload a cart
remotedeploy         Run the remotedeploy steps
restart              Restart a cart
restore              Restore an application
snapshot             Snapshot an application
start                Start the gear/cart
status               Get the status for a cart
stop                 Stop the gear/cart
```

Will any of this stuff help you stop and restart the gear? I'd start with the simple 'gear' command.  I don't remember, is Express loaded up via NPM or now native with node?  At one time it was a NPM install. Those don't get pushed to Openshift.

What is the directory tree structure on the openshift nodejs server?

```
root
   \ app-root
        \ data
        \ repo   <- -  the working files for web content end up here.
        \ runtime
   \ git
   \ nodejs
```

In openshift dependencies don't get pushed. For that you can login thru ssh and go to:
    `cd app-root/repo` or  `cd $OPENSHIFT_REPO_DIR` and then `npm install tool_of_choice`

Comment: in repo `express` is listed as you can see above

Answer (score 0):

I´ve readed this, maybe you  must use a port over 15000:

https://help.openshift.com/hc/en-us/articles/202185874-I-can-t-bind-to-a-port

Comment: https://help.openshift.com/hc/en-us/articles/203263674-What-external-ports-are-available-on-OpenShift-